# How does one send data through UART from MCU to your PC without any connections on TX/RX pins?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, uart

I have been reading up on UART, and I see it works by connecting TX<->RX and RX<->TX of receiver and transmitter. The example I couldn't wrap my head around though is your MCU being able to TX the data to a serial monitor that you could view on your PC using teraterm, let's say. I tried it and it does work.
I did specify the TX and RX pins for UART in my code, but they're not connected to anything. Can someone help me bridge this gap? Does it work like for RX too? (receiving data from the serial monitor into your MCU)?

Comment: there must be some connection between your MCU Tx pin and the PC's serial port Rx pin.  What MCU and develpoment board are you using?  What connections do you have between that board and the PC?

Comment: They must be connected to at least something! What platform or dev board you use? Nucleo maybe, with integrated ST-Link?

Comment: I have stm32f401re which uses cortex m4. i have the board connected to my laptop via USB.

Comment: You did not say on what board that micro is on! Knowing the MCU does not help.

Comment: Fairly certain that those TX/RX pins go to a chip like FT232 and your USB is actually sharing the TX/RX pins with the unconnected header.

Comment: @Justme - I did say STM32F401RE which is a dev board

Comment: @kol No it is not the name of the board, that is the name of your MCU. Clearly your dev board has lots of stuff in addition to the micro, like the programming and debugging interface. Is it a NUCLEO?

Comment: yes, nucleo. https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f401re.html

Answer (score 5):

Nucleo boards have integrated ST-Link which includes a USB serial port with TX/RX pins to the target MCU.

Comment: So I see ST-Link is a usb cable that has some pins including Tx/Rx.
But how come that data that I'm TXing on some pin that's unconnected to anything is being transmitted to my PC via ST-link?

Comment: Why do you claim they are unconnected? I already said in my answer that the F401 TX and RX pins are connected to the ST-Link chip. In addition to the programming and debugging interface, it also provides a USB serial port. You can verify it by looking at the schematics.

Comment: See section 6.8 USART Communication of the [STM32 Nucleo-64 Boards User Manual UM1724](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00105823-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the Tx/Rx lines of your MCU peripheral to USB to get to TeraTerm or Putty or `screen`. Check out [this part from adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954). It handles the USB protocol. Some MCU boards have a built in programmer (STMicro has STLink, Arduino has their own USB device programmer) and both connect to a UART but require the TTL/USB conversion.

Inside the cable there is an MCU that presents as a USB device (with all of the endpoints), and converts the transmission to async Rx/Tx. FTDI, PL2303 and SiLabs all make a part that does this in USB cable format, just make sure you only power from one source (e.g., don't plug in the USB cable of the eval board -and- supply power through the TTL/USB cable).