# How does built-in ST-link on a nucleo board communicate with the laptop through USB?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I'm trying to understand how USART works on a STM32 nucleo board that has a built-in ST-link. Here's the high level diagram I found from the user manual.

It's apparent that that RX and TX pins of the MCU are connected to TX and RX of the ST-link as expected, but what happens next? how does ST-link forward these signals to the laptop that's using serial interface for sending/receiving serial data?
[image: 32]

Comment: I already answered, but just noticed that this question is almost identical to what you previously asked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one send data through UART from MCU to your PC without any connections on TX/RX pins?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/496299/how-does-one-send-data-through-uart-from-mcu-to-your-pc-without-any-connections)

Answer (score 3):

ST-Link is also a USB serial adapter in addition to being a JTAG/SWD adapter. It basically shows up as USB COM port. All data, be it serial UART data or something else, goes in data packets via USB interface.

Comment: So if it weren't for ST-link, I wouldn't have seen a USB COM port that I do now? I just wanted to verify from the schematics

Comment: That's right. Remove the ST-Link and several USB devices will disappear,  including the COM port.